# Help with this 3-phase thyristor triggering board

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier, triac, thyristor, diac

I need a triggering board which is able to drive thyristors such as (s8006l), and I found this board on Aliexpress which might be the hidden gem I am looking for.

[enter link description here](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/4000510108384.html)
[enter link description here](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/4000321965732.html)

However my concern is that I want this board to be able to drive only one (half wave half controlled rectifier), two or even four thyristors and not only 6 thyristors (3-phase bridge type controlled rectifier) and the problem is the sellers just don't know if it can!.

According to some diagrams they included it mentioned that the board gives an error and stop producing pulses if not all outputs are connected to "Load", I am very curious how this claimed feedback work and if there is a way around it.

Simply the question I asked them " if I didn't connect all the K (cathode) and G (gate) signals , will the board give an error and stop producing output/pulses?"

[Datasheet](https://us-icbuim-file.oss-us-east-1.aliyuncs.com/file/7f9f1969e66a744b2c00cd007b79ebd4.pdf?Expires=1670710148&OSSAccessKeyId=LTAIxlzvmECyZvmX&Signature=QnN7k0ZpZMMggrXpLeAuhEkPvgs%3D&response-content-disposition=fileName%3D%E4%B8%89%E7%9B%B8%E8%A7%A6%E5%8F%91%E6%9D%BF.pdf)

Comment: Please link to a data sheet for the product. A pdf data sheet please.

Comment: I am sorry no datasheet is available only the pictures on the links I shared..

Comment: No datasheet = no sale.

Comment: No data sheet no good <-- professional EE perspective.

Comment: Datasheet added guys..

Comment: The datasheet link is blocked when I use Mozilla Firefox, but opens OK using Edge or Chrome. But I don't see where the datasheet has enough information to answer the OP's question.